# I'm afraid I've installed a scam npm package: how to analyse a Wasm?

Tags: node.js, webassembly, honeypot

I've installed and **executed** (with nodejs) a package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openssl.js

Somehow I didn't realize that it hasn't a good reputation (almost no activity/stars on twitter, github). Now I'm afraid that it is a scam. The worst case would be that is stealing/encrypting my data or something like that.

I've checked the processes, I/O and network in the activity monitor but nothing interesting.
But I would like to have more confidence that everything is okay.

Since it is a Wasm file I cannot just check the source code.
I've tried to decompile with this tool: https://github.com/WebAssembly/wabt but it gives me for all binaries in that project this error: `error: @0x00000004: bad magic value`.

Maybe because in the README of the openssl.js package they claim it is build with wasienv toolchain?

Another idea would be install a honeypot and run the same commands in the honeypot. But which honeypot is suitable for this?

// edit

I was able to run wasm2c on this file: **src/raw-wasm/openssl.wasm**.
But how can I ensure there was no network interactivity?
Here are the first lines of the output: https://pastebin.com/YYHecFAC

Comment: Author mentions it's still a testing project. Anyways it should be as easy as removing any npm package from project as these compilations are done as per projects. Fire up npm uninstall openssl.js and it will remove any changes made by the package to your project.

Comment: @MaulikParmar I am not sure if that is true - how can this undo the execution of commands?

Comment: The binary is compiled on per project basis as long as you do not include it globally. And you can check it by going to vendors package directory dist folder. You would find compiled binary along with compiled node bindings which are loaded at runtime. This is a way of sandboxing packages and prevent them from abusing package managers privileges, breaking other projects and keep application under security context.  It does same  when you install node-sass or node-dart or any other package which has C library binding. It executes Cmake to compile binary for your platform and then includes it.

Comment: I didn't installed it globally. But even if locally: what would be the worst case? I run the command (on a mac) without sudo. So during that run any code could be executed right? So my user files could be scanned (not the system files), but enough to access my private RSA keys and send them somewhere, right?

Comment: wabt is indeed the tool you want to use.  From the output it looks like that file is not actual a wasm file.  If you run `file` on the file what type of file does your OS think it is?

Comment: BYW, one of the nice features of wasm is that the wasm module can't actually make any system calls itself.  All it can do (in the context of node anyway) is call the JS functions that you give it.   If you want to see what its doing one way is to annotate all the imports you pass to it.

Comment: Okay I see. I found another wasm file under src/raw-wasm. I was able to decompile it with wabt2c. The output is not so helpful for me, but I'm not an expert. I just want to ensure there was no network interaction. From node.js I only passed the file system module to the the library. In the decompiled output I don't see any suspicious headers, but please verify if my assumption is correct: https://pastebin.com/YYHecFAC (first lines of the decompiled output)